# Getting a unique value from csv file in python

Tags: python, list, api, twitter, set

I have following code in Python for twitter api, How do i iterate to get the values from CSV file.

```
get_tweet = set()
gettweet_list = []
with open(TWEET_FILE) as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        gettweet_list.append(str(line))

get_tweet.update(set(gettweet_list))
del gettweet_list
if len(get_tweet) > 140: 
 get_tweet = get_tweet[:140]
 return get_tweet
```

Comment: What is happening currently? and what is the desired behavior ?

Comment: Currently the status says that it is exceeding the 140 char, so i guess it is taking all the values from CSV file rather taking only first row.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first how just get the first row:

```
with open(TWEET_FILE) as in_file:
    data = set(next(in_file).split())
```

You also cannot index a set so  `get_tweet[:140]` would never work.

If you want a set of all rows:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain
with open(TWEET_FILE) as in_file:
     data = set(chain.from_iterable(csv.reader(in_file)))
```

Sets also have no order so even turning it back into a list and slicing will not give you the first row.